# upgrade rails from 2.2.2 to 2.3.9 getting undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in upgrading rails app from 2.2.2 to 2.3.9 first error was:

```
D:\web>ruby script/server -trace
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- script/../config/boo
t (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

so i changed script/server from...

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
```

to:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
```

now i am getting:

```
D:\web>ruby script/server --trace
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:228:in `activate': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMet
hodError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1119:in `try_activate'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:32:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from D:/web/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from D:/web/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/server:4:in `<main>'

D:\web>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shot in the dark: update rubygems? gem update --system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is again some problem with railties plugin.
Maybe you should update it to version compatible with rails 2.3.9?

Also, there were problem with it after update of rubygems(it or some gem wanted gemcutter to work). And after updating rubygems to 1.3.6 gemcutter is uninstalled

Comment: I am wondering if I should just upgrade to rails 3 and get the pain over with.